# Looping through a map with structure as a key.

Tags: c++, struct, stdmap

I have a struct

```
struct key
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
 };
```

say x, y, z can take values from 1 to 10.

I also have a map

```
std::map<key,double> myMap;
```

which I populate with different key values.

Is there a way to loop through all the key values where say z=5. That is (in terms of pseudo code)

```
 loop over myMap
   double v += myMap.find({x=anything,y=anything,z=5})->second;
```

It would be very kind if someone can provide some comments as to whether this is achievable (I do not want to use boost containers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you sort `key` struct using z first, you may do it this way:

```
bool operator<( const key &k1, const key &k2 )
{
    return std::make_tuple( k1.z, k1.x, k1.y ) < std::make_tuple( k2.z, k2.x, k2.y ); // z must be first
}

auto min = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
auto end = map.lower_bound(  key{ min, min, 6 } );
for( auto it = map.lower_bound(  key{ min, min, 5 } ); it != end; ++it ) {
   ...
}
```

but if you need to iterate for x or y as well you will have to either create separate multimap per coordinate with pointer to structure or use `boost::multiindex`.

Comment: This is good but you better use `(5, INT_MIN, INT_MIN) => (5, INT_MAX, INT_MAX)` or something of the sort for your search bounds.  The ints here are signed.

Comment: Prefer [std::tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) for lexicographical comparison because it doesn't perform any copying. Also, `k1.y` and `k2.y` instead of `k1,y`, etc. Good answer.

Answer (score 5):

The standard associative containers use a one-dimensional ordering, i.e. they only know whether one key is less, equal or greater than another. So this is not efficiently possible. You can achieve such filtering in linear time using `std::find_if()`.

Maintaining `O(log n)` lookup time, it is however possible to create multiple maps, with different ways of indexing; e.g. one with X, one with Y and one with Z as the key. If the values are big objects, you could use pointers to not needlessly duplicate them. Of course, this can all be hidden behind an encapsulating class, that provides axis-based ordering to the outside.

Another approach, which is reasonable for small spaces (like x,y,z from 1 to 10), is to not use `std::map` but a 3D array/matrix instead. This can be implemented using a 1D `std::vector`, by mapping indices from 3 dimensions to 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 2500 // 2500 is the size of the array
```

Why not create an array of arrays like

```
double map[2][ARRAY_SIZE];
// map[0][x] - the key of Xth value in the array (example - 10th/1st/2nd ...)
// map[1][x] - the value of Xth value in the array
```

Just saying, it's better when you don't complicate !